# Java - byte[] to FileItem

Tags: file, jasper-reports, arrays, apache-commons

I'm using JasperReports to generate PDFs, and it gives me the PDF as a byte array, byte[].

I want to pass the raw bytes to another function that needs the file in terms of a FileItem object.  In particular, the FileItem is from the Apache Commons library `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem`.

```
// the function I want to pass it into
public DocumentDO toDocumentDO(FileItem fileItem);
```

Is there any way to do that or is it not possible (ie. the byte[] doesn't contain the metadata needed for it to be a FileItem like filename, mime type, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your byte array is just what it is - bunch ow raw bytes, all meta data that you mentioned needs to be provided separately unless you read it into the file and then parse the file for the embedded meta information